# Access Modifier VS Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, properties, access-modifiers

The purpose of Access modifiers is to hide data members from unauthorized access. while the purpose of Properties is to expose Access modifiers. Where the purpose of access modifier dies. The following is the example.

```
public class Employee
{
    private int EmployeeID;
    private string Name;
    private int Salary;

    public int EID { get { return this.EmployeeID; } set { this.EmployeeID = value; } }
    public string EName { get { return this.Name; } set { this.Name = value; } }
    public int ESalary { get { return this.Salary; } set { this.Salary = value; } }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee Employee = new Employee();
    Employee.EName = "Zaheer";
}
```

Here i can access property EName which indirectly access Name. Any comments nd sorry if the question is silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a private field is not that there is no way, whatsoever, for that value to be modified by something from outside of the type.  If that were true they would be entirely useless.  The idea of a private field is that *direct* access to the member itself is prohibited from outside of the type, but a limited degree of indirect access can be allowed through some number of non-private members.  Those public members will provide some more limited means of accessing the field than public access does.

In your particular example there really isn't much restriction taking place; the value can be accessed at any time by anyone with an instance, or set any time by anyone with an instance.  It's still a tad more protected than exposing the field publicly, for example you can't directly create a reference to the field through a `ref` parameter on a method, but you're right to say that there is very little protection added.  It becomes much more useful when the ability of an external entity to modify the field is limited in some way.  Perhaps it can get the value and not set it, perhaps certain values can't be set at all, perhaps it will change itself in ways never specified directly by any external entity when methods are called.

The idea at the end of the day is that the definition of the methods/properties will determine what level of access there is to the underlying fields.  That level of access can range from almost complete to almost nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You got it a bit wrong. Properties are data members and access modifiers are the ones that modify the access to the data members. Properties are accessible from outside because they have the 'public' access modifier.

Comment: Yeah you are right but thing is that i can still access private members. I think it shouldn't allowed....

Comment: Also looking on your syntax, you will want to standardize the naming of your fields like this: public fields (also known as properties) will have their name starting with capital letter while private fields will have the initial letter in lowercase.

Comment: You can't access private members from another class that the one they belong to. What you are accessing in your code is the EName property which is public.

Comment: But indirectly I'm assigning value to private member Name. This is what i think i shouldn't access from main method

Comment: That's what public members are used for: to handle internal class functionality. Think of your EName property as of a method "public void SetName(string value)" that will set the Name field value with the given parameter. In fact properties are what one of the answers here mentioned: syntactic sugar for methods.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are actually a syntactic sugar for methods that return and set a value of a field. Therefore, they have several advantages:

1. Properties can perform additional checks. Like, you can catch attempts to set `EID` to a negative value or `EName` to an empty string.
2. Properties can set several fields at once to keep the inner data of the object consistent.
3. Properties can be used in interfaces, while fields cannot.
4. Properties can have separate access modifiers for getters and setters.

However, setting a field is more efficient because it does not have the overhead of invoking a method.

Answer (score 1):

Your example properties are all very simple and could be replaced by automatic properties. Properties are used to control the access to a field, not just to expose the field.

As an example, if you have a property called `EmailAddress`, you might want to check the value for a proper email address before it is assigned. You can handle that in the setter of the property and reject any invalid values. You cannot control this inside your class when you expose a field directly.

This is one of the obvious uses of a property, but there are other uses and advantages over using fields.